# Moving rigidbody

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I am new to unity and I have a object that I want to move.
But this object doesn't move at all. It changes his direction so the object can look to the left/right but it doesn't move from the point he starts.

So basicly the object can rotate but not move in any direction.

The question is: How can I make the object move

```
public float movementSpeed = 20;
Animator anim;
Rigidbody rb;

public Text countText;
public Text winText;

private int count;

void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    count = 0;
    SetCountText();
    winText.text = "";
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    ControllPlayer();
}

void ControllPlayer()
{
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    float moveVertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

    if (movement != Vector3.zero)
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(movement), 0.15f);
        anim.SetInteger("Walk", 1);
    }
    else
    {
        anim.SetInteger("Walk", 0);
    }


    rb.addForce(movement * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

}

public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Pick Up"))
    {
        other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        count = count + 1;
        SetCountText();
    }
}

void SetCountText()
{
    countText.text = "Food: " + count.ToString();
    if (count >= 10)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Victory");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a little overcomplicated for what you need to do.

I don't really do stuff in the 3D world at the moment, but a quick YouTube search brought up [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sXQI_0ILEW4) video.

The code he used was

```
transform.Translate(moveSpeed*Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")*Time.deltaTime,0f,moveSpeed*Input.GetAxis("Vertical")*Time.deltaTime);
```

inside the `Update()` method, with `moveSpeed` being a public variable so you can change it in the inspector.

You could then do a check to see if you're moving and set the animation values accordingly.

I would always recommend putting player movement inside the `Update()`method as otherwise it can feel laggy and miss key presses, especially if you have a lot going on - eg a double jump.

Hope this helps, and good luck with Unity :).

By the way, as you're new I would already recommend searching Youtube first for a tutorial - most of the time someone has done one on what you want to do. Creators like [Brackeys](https://www.youtube.com/user/Brackeys) have a massive backlog of stuff which is really useful.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment! Well I had already something that worked `transform.Translate(movement * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);`
 but my teacher said that it could be more easier to use `rb.addforce` but I can't get it to work. But anyways thank you so much for your comment!

Comment: If you want to use the physics system, you must use `AddForce`. Could you place an screenshot of you RigidBody component? Maybe you set the property `IsKinematic` to `true`.